# HTML anchor tag have href first then onclick()

Tags: javascript, html

In an anchor tag with both href and onClick, is it possible to have the href first go to the link then execute the onClick()?

For example, I want this anchor tag to first go to the link and then call the highlightButton function.

```html
<a
  class="page-link" 
  href="?page={{step.previous_page_number}}" 
  onClick="highlightButton();"
  aria-label="Previous"
>Previous</a>
```

Comment: No, navigating from the current page will abort any in-progress scripts

Answer (score 2):

Nope. You can, however, check and validate the parameter `page` from the URL when the document is ready then execute the highlightButton() function.

Example:

HTML

```
<a class="page-link" href="?page={{step.previous_page_number}}" aria label="Previous">Previous</a>
```

javaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const page = params.get("page");

    // Example Validation
    if (page != "" || page != null) {
        highlightButton();
    }

    function highlightButton() {
        // Code goes here
    }
});
```

Comment: Three points... 1) this isn't tagged [tag:jquery] so it's best to avoid it in your answer. 2) Why wouldn't you use the current page's location? `const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search); const page = params.get("page");` 3) What's with `helloWorld`? OP just said they want to call the function

Comment: @Phil 1) Right, I updated the answer to javaScript. 2) There are multiple ways to search parameters from the URL. What I've shown is okay, what you suggest is also okay. As long as it works. 3) `helloWorld` is just an example of the equivalence of `{{step.previous_page_number}}` for the href

Comment: OP hasn't said anything about using the query parameters or conditionally running the `highlightButton()` function. Treat your answer as if OP will directly copy and paste your code (because they will)

Comment: What I've understood about the problem is: 1st OP wants to redirect the page; 2nd OP wants to execute `highlightButton()`; So the first solution that came to my mind is: 1st Redirect page by clicking `a href` tag - adding a `page` parameter in the URL; 2nd To execute `highlightButton()` check the URL parameters - that is, to check if the `page` parameter is in the URL

Answer (score 1):

No, You cannot do that, by opening a new link, the last page wont work at the background but if you want to use a specific function in the next page, just write the function and call it at the top of your script tag!

Like this :

```
<script>
    highlightButton()
    function highlightButton() {
        // your code 
    }
</script>
```